# Android Wear : canvas.drawbitmpap not aligned depending screen size

Tags: java, android, canvas, wear-os

I am trying to build a watchface with a battery level gauge using a png file for each segment.

I scale them depending on the screen width, using the coordinates starting from the middle of the screen, so I think it should work whatever the screen resolution. But, depending of the resolution of the screen, the segments are not correctly aligned. 
For example, with a 320x320 screen resolution, it's perfectly aligned, but when I try my code on a 240x240px, or 360x360px screen, some segments are not aligned
What am I doing wrong?

```
BatteryMarkerW100Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mark_w100);
scale = ((float) screenWidth) / (float) BatteryMarkerW100Bitmap.getWidth();
BatteryMarkerW100Bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BatteryMarkerW100Bitmap,
                (int) (BatteryMarkerW100Bitmap.getWidth() * scale * 0.1342f),
                (int) (BatteryMarkerW100Bitmap.getHeight() * scale * 0.1342f), true);

BatteryMarkerW80Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mark_w80);
scale = ((float) screenWidth) / (float) BatteryMarkerW80Bitmap.getWidth();
BatteryMarkerW80Bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BatteryMarkerW80Bitmap,
        (int) (BatteryMarkerW80Bitmap.getWidth() * scale * 0.1218f),
        (int) (BatteryMarkerW80Bitmap.getHeight() * scale * 0.1218f), true);

BatteryMarkerW60Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mark_w60);
scale = ((float) screenWidth) / (float) BatteryMarkerW60Bitmap.getWidth();
BatteryMarkerW60Bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BatteryMarkerW60Bitmap,
        (int) (BatteryMarkerW60Bitmap.getWidth() * scale * 0.115f),
        (int) (BatteryMarkerW60Bitmap.getHeight() * scale * 0.115f), true);

BatteryMarkerW40Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mark_w40);
scale = ((float) screenWidth) / (float) BatteryMarkerW40Bitmap.getWidth();
BatteryMarkerW40Bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BatteryMarkerW40Bitmap,
        (int) (BatteryMarkerW40Bitmap.getWidth() * scale * 0.107f),
        (int) (BatteryMarkerW40Bitmap.getHeight() * scale * 0.107f), true);

BatteryMarkerW20Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mark_w20);
scale = ((float) screenWidth) / (float) BatteryMarkerW20Bitmap.getWidth();
BatteryMarkerW20Bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BatteryMarkerW20Bitmap,
        (int) (BatteryMarkerW20Bitmap.getWidth() * scale * 0.115f),
        (int) (BatteryMarkerW20Bitmap.getHeight() * scale * 0.115f), true);

if (batteryWatchLevel >= 80) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(BatteryMarkerW100Bitmap, mCenterX * 0.0843f, mCenterY * 1.325f, BatteryMarkerPaint);
}
if (batteryWatchLevel >= 60) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(BatteryMarkerW80Bitmap, mCenterX * 0.128f, mCenterY * 1.425f, BatteryMarkerPaint);
}
if (batteryWatchLevel >= 40) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(BatteryMarkerW60Bitmap, mCenterX * 0.18f, mCenterY * 1.538f, BatteryMarkerPaint);
}
if (batteryWatchLevel >= 20) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(BatteryMarkerW40Bitmap, mCenterX * 0.27f, mCenterY * 1.65f, BatteryMarkerPaint);
}
if (batteryWatchLevel >= 0) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(BatteryMarkerW20Bitmap, mCenterX * 0.388f, mCenterY * 1.76f, BatteryMarkerPaint);
}
```

Comment: Did you perhaps put the assets in a drawable folder that results in them being automatically scaled by the system depending on the target device's dpi?

Comment: I put png files in the drawable-nodpi folder. 
But  i get around the problem buy using one png for the full gauge. I made 5 png for 20-40-60-80-100% level battery, and empty segments unused have the same color as the background. I did it instead of using one png for each segment. 
Maybe the system have some dificulties to scale and position the bitmaps precisely when they are too small, or something like that ?